Compare Images Using Discrete Fourier Transform
I want to use Discrete Fourier Transform to compare a sample image with each image in a folder. The images are portraits, taken straight on. I use the face_recognition module to find faces. However, the performance is not high, and the results are quite similar across the images and do not produce the desired outcome.
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from skimage.metrics import structural_similarity as ssim

# Load the pre-trained dlib model for face landmark detection
def dft_magnitude(image):
    fourier = cv2.dft(np.float32(image), flags=cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

    fourier_shift = np.fft.fftshift(fourier)

    magnitude = 20 * np.log(cv2.magnitude(fourier_shift[:, :, 0], fourier_shift[:, :, 1]) + 1700)
    return magnitude
    

def compare_images(img1, img2):
    dft_img1 = dft_magnitude(img1)
    dft_img2 = dft_magnitude(img2)
    
    # Normalize the magnitude images to the range [0, 1]
    dft_img1 = cv2.normalize(dft_img1, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
    dft_img2 = cv2.normalize(dft_img2, None, 0, 1, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    # Compute SSIM
    ssim_similarity = ssim(dft_img1, dft_img2, data_range=dft_img1.max() - dft_img1.min())
    
    return ssim_similarity

def find_face(image):
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(image) #y1, x2, y2, x1 - two angles of rectangle shape
    if not face_locations:
        return None
    top, right, bottom, left = face_locations[0]
    face_image = image[top:bottom, left:right]

    return face_image

# Example usage
sample_image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
target_image = cv2.imread('3.jpg')

similarity_score = compare_images(sample_image, target_image)
print(f'Similarity score: {similarity_score}')


I tried to change the magnitude, but result wasn't a expectation. Please help me.

I can't see that comparing them in the FFT domain is going to get you very far. Zero out the likely very dominant DC components of both images and it might just possibly pick up enough structure in the face enough to be acceptable. With DC  included you will be mostly comparing the colour of the wall behind the sitter.

I don't know the face recognition framework you are using but here some improvements: 1) shrink the image to a smaller size before running image recognition. 2) use a thread pool (at least 2 threads) to run recognition of multiple images in parallel, this way the time required to load the images from the disk won't affect the total elapsed; the only bottleneck will be your CPU speed.
